# DateDiff equivalent in Linq MVC

Tags: jquery, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Im currently working on a date comparison page and a co-worker of mine gave a SQL Query that I need to convert on a Linq. but Im not that familiar with `DATEDIFF` in SQL

So Here is the SQL Query

```
,case when  DATEDIFF(day, isnull(a.NewWorkerDate,a.Workerdate), a.Workerdate)=0 then 'NEWWORKER' ELSE 'OLDWORKER' End as WorkerType
```

I tried something like this but gets different output

```
var WorkerType = (from a in db.Workers
                  where a.IsDeleted = false
                   && a.ID == workerId
                  select new WorkerModel{
                       WorkerType = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(a.NewWorkerDate, a.Workerdate) = 0 ? "NEWWORKER" : "OLDWORKER" 
}).FirstOrDefault;
```

How does the `isnull` going to take place and where ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, `EntityFunctions` is obsolete and it is recommended to use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffDays` instead. Also you can use `??` to handle `null` value:

```
var WorkerType = (from a in db.Workers
                  where a.IsDeleted == false
                   && a.ID == workerId
                  select new {
                       WorkerType = DbFunctions.DiffDays
                                      (a.NewWorkerDate ?? a.Workerdate, a.Workerdate)  == 0 ? 
                                      "NEWWORKER" : "OLDWORKER" 
      }).FirstOrDefault();
```